# What is the reference in terms of XYZ 3D coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, physics

I need to **choose a coordinate system for a drone position**.

I wonder which of...

- `A` The coordinate system used as reference for the spherical coordinate system (Z pointing up)
- `B` The coordinate system mostly used in virtual 3D environments (*Unity*, *ThreeJS*) (Y pointing up)

...are mostly used and logical in my case (a drone position)

---

`A` representation :
[image: First choice (A) of coordinate system]

`B` representation:
[image: Second choice (B) of coordinate system]

Comment: (imho) **Both** is OK. coz it is interchangeable to each other.. afaik what matters more (for the selection) is your pros and cons of using it.. any details on the pros n cons for each selection in your mind?

Comment: It depends on the field and in practice. Mathematicians and physicists often use different conventions for phi and theta in spherical coordinates, so always worth checking!